# Does aliasing tables names in large queries have noticeable impact on performance?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, rdbms

Does aliasing tables names in large queries have noticeable impact on performance?
Aliasing:

```
...
...
FROM table_1 T1
...
...
...
```

Is it significantly different for the various DB systems out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a [discussion about this topic](http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/7848/45218.aspx#45218) already.  In short, there is no significant impact on performance caused by aliasing table names.

Comment: Hit by the drive-byes, again.  Downvoters, please leave comments, so I can fix what was wrong.

Comment: For some reason SQL questions attract a lot of downvotes for making suggestions or just even answering :) I enjoyed the link though so I voted you up.

Answer (score 2):

No.  None whatsoever.

Comment: Only as long as there's no bug in your DBMS: Bad performance when using alias vs. base table in outer join query. (In an older DB2 version: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IY58735) ;-)